# OpenAI ChatGPT API error: "InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied: messages"

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am currently trying to use OpenAI's most recent model: `gpt-3.5-turbo`. I am following a very [basic tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0l4UDn1p7gM&ab_channel=TinkeringwithDeepLearning%26AI).

I am working from a Google Collab notebook. I have to make a request for each prompt in a list of prompts, which for sake of simplicity looks like this:

```
prompts = ['What are your functionalities?', 'what is the best name for an ice-cream shop?', 'who won the premier league last year?']
```

I defined a function to do so:

```
import openai

# Load your API key from an environment variable or secret management service
openai.api_key = 'my_API'

def get_response(prompts: list, model = "gpt-3.5-turbo"):
  responses = []

  
  restart_sequence = "\n"

  for item in prompts:

      response = openai.Completion.create(
      model=model,
      messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
      temperature=0,
      max_tokens=20,
      top_p=1,
      frequency_penalty=0,
      presence_penalty=0
    )

      responses.append(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'])

  return responses
```

However, when I call `responses = get_response(prompts=prompts[0:3])` I get the following error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied: messages
```

Any suggestions?

Replacing the `messages` argument with `prompt` leads to the following error:

```
InvalidRequestError: [{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What are your functionalities?'}] is valid under each of {'type': 'array', 'minItems': 1, 'items': {'oneOf': [{'type': 'integer'}, {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'buffer': {'type': 'string', 'description': 'A serialized numpy buffer'}, 'shape': {'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'integer'}, 'description': 'Array shape'}, 'dtype': {'type': 'string', 'description': 'Stringified dtype'}, 'token': {'type': 'string'}}}]}, 'example': '[1, 1313, 451, {"buffer": "abcdefgh", "shape": [1024], "dtype": "float16"}]'}, {'type': 'array', 'minItems': 1, 'maxItems': 2048, 'items': {'oneOf': [{'type': 'string'}, {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'buffer': {'type': 'string', 'description': 'A serialized numpy buffer'}, 'shape': {'type': 'array', 'items': {'type': 'integer'}, 'description': 'Array shape'}, 'dtype': {'type': 'string', 'description': 'Stringified dtype'}, 'token': {'type': 'string'}}}], 'default': '', 'example': 'This is a test.', 'nullable': False}} - 'prompt'
```

Comment: `messages` isn't the correct argument. Guess you need `prompt: []`

Comment: @0stone0 the messages argument is the one provided in the documentation. However, implementing your solution leads to another error message (check the most recent **edit**)

Comment: But the prompt just need to be your question: `prompt: item`

Comment: @0stone0 This leads to a different error which I believe has to do with the model (your solution would work, e.g., with a ***davinci*** model.

***InvalidRequestError: This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?***

Comment: Oke I made some code myself and can't reproduce your problem. Works fine over here.

Comment: Sure you are using the latest version of the `openai` package?

Comment: error I get is `openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'message': 'This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'model', 'code': None}}`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Problem

**You used the wrong method name to get a completion.** When using the OpenAI SDK (Python or Node.js), you need to use the right method name.

Which method name is the right one? It depends on the OpenAI model you want to use.

### Solution

The tables below will help you figure out which method name is the right one for a given OpenAI model.

First, find in the table below which API endpoint is compatible with the OpenAI model you want to use.

| API endpoint | Model group | Model name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /v1/chat/completions | • GPT-4 • GPT-3.5 | • `gpt-4` and dated model releases • `gpt-4-32k` and dated model releases • `gpt-4-1106-preview` • `gpt-4-vision-preview` • `gpt-3.5-turbo` and dated model releases • `gpt-3.5-turbo-16k` and dated model releases • fine-tuned versions of `gpt-3.5-turbo` |
| /v1/completions (Legacy) | • GPT-3.5 • GPT base | • `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` • `babbage-002` • `davinci-002` |
| /v1/assistants |  | All models except `gpt-3.5-turbo-0301` supported. Retrieval tool requires `gpt-4-1106-preview` or `gpt-3.5-turbo-1106`. |
| /v1/audio/transcriptions | Whisper | • `whisper-1` |
| /v1/audio/translations | Whisper | • `whisper-1` |
| /v1/audio/speech | TTS | • `tts-1` • `tts-1-hd` |
| /v1/fine_tuning/jobs | • GPT-3.5 • GPT base | • `gpt-3.5-turbo` • `babbage-002` • `davinci-002` |
| /v1/embeddings | Embeddings | • `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| /v1/moderations | Moderations | • `text-moderation-stable` • `text-moderation-latest` |

Second, find in the table below which method name you need to use.

*Note: Pay attention, because you have to use the method name that is compatible with your OpenAI SDK version.*

| API endpoint | Python SDK <`v1` method name | Python SDK `v1` method name | Node.js SDK `v3` method name | Node.js SDK `v4` method name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /v1/chat/completions | openai.ChatCompletion.create | openai.chat.completions.create | openai.createChatCompletion | openai.chat.completions.create |
| /v1/completions (Legacy) | openai.Completion.create | openai.completions.create | openai.createCompletion | openai.completions.create |
| /v1/assistants | / | openai.beta.assistants.create | / | openai.beta.assistants.create |
| /v1/audio/transcriptions | openai.Audio.transcribe | openai.audio.transcriptions.create | openai.createTranscription | openai.audio.transcriptions.create |
| /v1/audio/translations | openai.Audio.translate | openai.audio.translations.create | openai.createTranslation | openai.audio.translations.create |
| /v1/audio/speech | / | openai.audio.speech.create | / | openai.audio.speech.create |
| /v1/fine_tuning/jobs | / | openai.fine_tuning.jobs.create | / | openai.fineTuning.jobs.create |
| /v1/embeddings | openai.Embedding.create | openai.embeddings.create | openai.createEmbedding | openai.embeddings.create |
| /v1/moderations | openai.Moderation.create | openai.moderations.create | openai.createModeration | openai.moderations.create |

##### Python SDK `v1` working example for the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model (i.e., [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/chat-completions-api))

If you run `test.py`, the OpenAI API will return the following completion:

> Hello there! How can I assist you today?

**test.py**

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
  messages = [
    {'role': 'user', 'content': 'Hello!'}
  ],
  temperature = 0  
)

print(completion.choices[0].message.content)
```

##### Node.js SDK `v4` working example for the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model (i.e., [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/chat-completions-api))

If you run `test.js`, the OpenAI API will return the following completion:

> Hello there! How can I assist you today?

**test.js**

```
const OpenAI = require("openai");
const client = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
    
async function main() {
  const completion = await client.chat.completions.create({
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    messages: [
      { role: 'user', content: 'Hello!' }
    ],
    temperature: 0,
  });

  console.log(completion.choices[0].message.content);
}

main();
```

Comment: This: I think the naming practices at OpenAI made it a bit confusing, Why would you have this in the introduction example:

```import openai

openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
    ]
)```

Comment: I agree, it's a bit confusing. I think they should copy-paste the example from the documentation.

Comment: This is Pytthon, right? What's the nodejs equivalent? I had `const completion = await openai.createCompletion({....})` but I get the error "This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?"

Comment: Super helpful~! In my case, I used a wrong class, so instead of `openai.ChatCompletion.create()`, I used the wrong one `openai.Completion.create()`. And OpenAI happens to have both `ChatCompletion` and `Completion` which makes this issue harder to be found.

Answer (score 3):

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
model='gpt-3.5-turbo',
  messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": "What is openAI?"}],
max_tokens=193,
temperature=0,
)

print(response)
print(response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"])
```

Comment: This answer could benefit from literally any explanation at all. Code-only answers are rarely useful, especially as time goes on.

Answer (score 2):

For gpt4 this is what worked for me

```py
        for prompt in prompts:
            # from openai import OpenAI
            # client = OpenAI(api_key=openai.api_key)
            print(f'{self.model_name=}')
            response = openai.chat.completions.create(
            # response = client.chat.completions.create(
                model = self.model_name,
                messages = 
                [
                    # {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
                    {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
                ],
                temperature = temperature 
            )
            generated_text: str = response.choices[0].message.content.strip()
            generated_texts.append(generated_text)
```

when error

```
openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'message': 'This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'model', 'code': None}}
```

appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]` outside of your response variable and call that in response variable like:

```py
messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
for item in prompts:
      response = openai.Completion.create(
      model=model,
      messages=messages,
      temperature=0,
      max_tokens=20,
      top_p=1,
      frequency_penalty=0,
      presence_penalty=0
    )
```